# DRY controller .valid? for create and update using simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, simple-form, dry

So I've got these views:

new.html.erb

```
<div class="booyah-box col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
<h1>Expose Your Hidden Gem</h1>
<%= simple_form_for @place do |f| %>

<%= f.input :name, error: "Name is mandatory" %>
<%= f.input :address %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<br />
<%= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<div class="booyah-box col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
<h1>Edit Your Place</h1>
<%= simple_form_for @place do |f| %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :address %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<br />
<%= f.submit 'Update', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

this model:
Place.rb

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :photos
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode

validates :name, presence: true
validates :address, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
end
```

And finally, places_controller.rb (only showing create and update)

```
  def create
  @place = current_user.places.create(place_params)
  if @place.save
  redirect_to root_path
  else
  render :new
  end
  end

 def update
 @place = Place.find(params[:id])
 if @place.user != current_user
 return render text: 'Not Allowed', status: :forbidden
 end
 @place.update_attributes(place_params)
 if @place.save
  redirect_to root_path
 else
  render :edit
 end
 end
```

But, I'm trying to think DRY and want to know if there is a better way to do a validation for name address and description presence without having the same identical code in both the create and update portions of my controller? I feel like I should just be writing it once...

Answer (score 0):

First, you can refactor your views to use the following structure:

```
# new.html.erb
<div class="booyah-box col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
  <h1>Expose Your Hidden Gem</h1>
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>

# edit.html.erb
<div class="booyah-box col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
  <h1>Edit Your Place</h1>
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>

# _form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @place do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <br />
  <% submit_label = @place.new_record? ? 'Create' : 'Update' %>
  <%= f.submit submit_label, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

And then in your controllers you could refactor to:

```
def create
  @place = current_user.places.new(place_params)
  if @place.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def update
  @place = current_user.places.find(params[:id])
  @place.attributes = place_params
  if @place.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```